# How can i get credentials using Powershell script in Jenkins?

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am trying to run a Jenkins job that asks for a users credentials and sets global variables. This is a Powershell script in Jenkins Job I use:

```
 $pscredential = Get-Credential
 $global:uname=$pscredential.UserName
 $global:upwd=$pscredential.Password

 Write-Host $global:uname
 Write-Host $global:upwd
```

The job is run from a remote machine initiated by the user, so i would have thought they would get a pop up and the details they provide would be passed through to the Jenkins job.

The call to Get-Credential doesn't bring up the login screen for the user. How can i get the user credentials or is there another cmd i should be using?